# Pagination Architecture

Tags: php, architecture, pagination

I just recently realized that what I thought was a foolproof approach to pagination isn't so foolproof after all. What I mean by foolproof is that the pagination or fruits thereof meet the following two conditions:

1. the newest posts must always be displayed on the index page
2. each post must always be displayed on the same page, so it is accessible in the future

Before I started creating the pagination functionality, I realized that it wouldn't be very user friendly if I were to treat `index.php` as `page 1` and continually append pages with new content thereto. Who wants to see the same `page 1` with the same content every time they visit your site? Nobody should have to manually navigate to the new content every time they visit your site.

My solution to the above issue was to always treat `index.php` as the very last page. I had believed that this had solved the issue completely, but I obviously didn't think it through. Even though this approach is better because the newest content and the newest page is always reflected on `index.php`, I realized last night while laying in bed that, if I always populate `index.php` to its maximum capacity of, say, 10 posts, then the remainder of posts ($postCount % 10) will always be displayed on `page 1`, and therefore all posts will still continually shift back and forth 9 positions. For instance, if there were only 10 posts, all of them would show up on `page 1`, but as soon as somebody submits the 11th post, all the posts but the oldest or very 1st one will show up on `page 2`; Further, if an additional 9 posts were published, the newest 10 would show up on `page 2` and the oldest 10 would show up on `page 1 as expected; but, again, as soon as somebody publishes the 21st post, then the newest 10 would show up on`page 3`, the next newest 10 would show up on`page 2`, and the oldest post would obviously show up on`page 1`.

An obvious "solution" or "fix" to this problem would be to not fully populate `index.php` with 10 posts and instead display the remainder on `index.php`. But for what I hope are obvious reasons I do not want to do this.

Has anybody experienced and dealt with this issue before? **How can I design the architecture so that `index.php` is always the newest page with the newest content, yet posts can always be found on the same page while not shifting around at all?**

Any help or insight would be GREATLY appreciated!!! <3

Answer (score 1):

The big question is: do you really need a "page numeration"?

What I have recently adopted is a bit different pagination schema. I list the items based on the a *border conditions*: and id of the item, that exists outside the next page.

Let's say you have a page containing items `41`, `39` `35` and `34`. The previous page would be the 4 items, that are *after 41* and the next page would be the 4 items, that are *before 34*. So the links that you end up with are:

- first page: `/list?limit=4`
- next page: `/list?before=34&limit=4`
- previous page: `/list?after=41&limit=4`
- last page: `/list?after=0&limit=4`

And in this case, the "next" page" would contain items `33`, `32`, `30` and `29` ... and you can use the IDs from this page to compute the new navigation.

The major downside is that you do not have a "page counter" anywhere. But what you get instead are pages, that always will contain the expected elements (unless those have been deleted), ability to cache the content and built-in handling for "what to do if there is no such element" state. As a minor bonus, you also get a bit better performance in SQL side of things, dues to not having to use [offset](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).

I personally begun using this approach, when working on REST API structures.

Comment: Hm.. I'm struggling to understand how the same elements would always appear on the same page with your approach? **Further, I've come to the conclusion that, as long as you're displaying a fixed number of items on each page (say, 4 or 10) and guaranteeing that each item always remains on the same page, you're always going to have one page with fewer than the fixed number (fewer than 4 or 10) when there is a remainder of pages (5 or 11 or whatever).** On another note, the reason I want to include pagination is to make it easier to relocate specific posts and or easier to dig through the archive

Comment: [continued] ...at least until I implement search and filter functionalities. But this will come after I'm able to validate a market for the product with the MVP.

Comment: The point of the approach, that I described, is to ensure that a given link to a page will always contain the same items (you can share/bookmark/cache that page). But this does not mean, that you can have unchanging page 1, page 4 or page 31, because in this form of pagination you do not have a concept of "enumerate page". And I have no idea how any of this impacts archive/history.

Comment: the only actual "solutions" to my problem, it seems, are either displaying the newest content at the bottom of the stack (on the very last page) or diisplaying the page with the newest content even though it might have as few posts as 1 on it.